# How to Move the mouse using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, mouse, sendkeys

I am trying to move the mouse using VBScript. I tried to use  Sendkeys `"{CLICK LEFT , x , y}"` and Sendkeys `"{MOVETO, 10 , 20}"` but it isn't working i also tried to use MouseKeys, so i could move it with the keyboard and therefore use `Sendkeys` to activate it but it also did not work (the mousekeys numpad is not moving the mouse). I've tried everything I know and what i could research elsewhere, so now I hope one of you can answer this for me. thxs

Comment: VBScript can't do what you're asking for. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Answer (score 6):

One possible way to move the mouse is:

```
Dim Excel: Set Excel = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
Excel.ExecuteExcel4Macro "CALL(""user32"",""SetCursorPos"",""JJJ"",""xxx"",""yyy"")"
```

-->xxx = X Position
   | yyy = y Position

The only disadvantage is that you need Microsoft Excel to run this script...

Hope I could help you

Answer (score 3):

VBScript can't do this natively. You'd have to do some calls to the Windows API or some other library that can do this for you.

As an alternative, you may want to consider a different scripting language, like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) which can do this in one simple line of code for you.